# Suppose $X_{n+1} = 2X_n - X_{n-1} + Z_n$. What is the value function and backward equation to calculate $P(X_T > 1 \mid X_0 = X_1 = 0)$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

> Suppose $X_{n+1} = 2X_n - X_{n-1} + Z_n$ where $Z_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ i.i.d. Describe the value function and backward equation that can be used to calculate $P(X_T > 1 \mid X_0 = X_1 = 0)$.

At first glance, this seems straightforward and it probably is. I am lost at understanding how to implement a backward equation with discrete Gaussian recurrence relation rather than a continuous stochastic process. I believe the solution is a PDE rather than a matrix, this is because the state space is clearly continuous. Finally, I would guess that the value function 
$$ V(X_T) = \begin{cases} 1, & X_T > 1 \\ 0, & X_T \leq 0 \end{cases}$$
would suffice for what we need.

I start with $\mathbb{E}[V(X_T) \mid \mathcal{F}_t]$ for $t < T$ and try to work my way backwards using the tower property but as I said earlier, iI can ony figure out how to do this in continuous time rather than discrete time. Help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Another thought: since the process is clearly Gaussian, perhaps we can use the heat equation to solve.

Comment: You can directly show that $X_T=\sum_{i=1}^{T-1} (T-i)Z_i\sim N(0,\frac {(T-1)T(2T-1)}6)$ by summing the difference equation.

Comment: @A.S. that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the remark. Although does that get us anywhere in terms of understanding how to use a value function and backward equation to solve the question? I'm doing this as practice and would like to understand the question using the method as stated. Appreciate your remarks though.

Comment: You have a Markov process on states $Y_i=(X_i.X_{i+1})$ with the backwards equation $f(y,t)=\int P(y\to y')f(y',t+1)\,dy'$.